# Image_tag src did not changed dynamically with controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, controller

I want to make `image_tag` src dynamically changed via `link_to`.

So I make `link_to`. This link contain params. In controller my instance variable`@selected_creator` get this params successfully. And I confirm my instance variable is changed in view file, too. But my `image_tag`src is not changed. Did I must use with jquery? If then how can I render it?

#### creators/_row.html.erb

```
<% @creators.each do |creator| %>
    <%= link_to 'select', creators_path(id: creator.id), :remote => true  %>
<% end %>
```

#### creators_controller.rb

```
def index
    @creators = Creator.all

    if params[:id]
        @selected_creator = Creator.find_by_id(params[:id])
    else
        @selected_creator = nil
    end
end
```

#### creators/index.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag "#{@selected_creator.asset.url(:medium)}", :id => 'selected-creator' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `:remote => true` which means that when you click the link, you're doing an ajax request. so you should create an `erb` template called `index.js.erb` which contains something like this:

```
$("#selected-creator").attr("src", <%= @selected_creator.asset.url(:medium) %>);
```

You'll also need to add `respond_to :js` to your controller so that it looks like this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js

  def index
    #rest of code
  end
end
```

Comment: true, I missed that. He will also need to add `respond_to :js` to the controller.

Comment: I did it, but rails get error, undefined method 'asset'. Maybe `@selected_creator` is `nil` on first loading so error. I think I must make new method in controller.

Comment: @Penguin you should make sure that `@selected_creator` is not `nil` and that it has a method called `asset`. You should also note that `index.js.erb` only gets rendered when you click the link. When you visit your page normally `index.html.erb` gets rendered instead.

Comment: Thanks I got hint with your answer. I got parameter with ajax. I share my code https://jsfiddle.net/say8425/2mL0h61g/